# Microsoft Graph Todo Class Not Found

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having a perplexing problem using Microsoft Graph API. I want to get a list of Todo lists and add a task to the default one. My code is:

```
$response = $graph->createRequest('GET','/me/todo/lists')
                ->setReturnType(Model\Todo::class)
                ->execute();
```

I get a " Class 'Microsoft\Graph\Model\Todo' not found" error. If I replace Todo::class with Event::class, it works. If I replace it with Planner::class, it works. Of course, those classes won't do me any good. I have verified the Todo.php file exists.

I have this at the top of my script:

```
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of the [SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) are you using?

Comment: I tested this with v 1.31 and 1.33 both don't give the class not found error. If you are using another version, try updating.

Comment: It's 1.33. I went with using curl to POST and GET and it all works fine now.